SwiftUI ToolbarItems do not show in iOS18
I have a BusStopsViewControllerRepresentable that contains a BusStopsController which pushes to a BusStopsDetailView. In the BusStopsDetailView, it contains another BusStopDetailViewControllerRepresentable that has toolbarItems. For some reason, these toolbarItems are not shown in iOS18, but shown on iOS17.
Code:
//BusStopsViewControllerRepresentable
struct BusStopsViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var busStopsViewModel: BusStopsViewModel
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let controller = BusStopsController(busStopsViewModel: busStopsViewModel)
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        return navigationController
    }
}

class BusStopsController: UIViewController {
// ...
    func annotationViewDidTap(busStopEntity: BusStopEntity) {
        let detailView = BusStopDetailView(busStop: busStopEntity).environmentObject(busStopsViewModel)
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: detailView)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }
}

//BusStopDetailView
struct BusStopDetailView: View {
    //...
    
    var body: some View {
        BusStopDetailViewControllerRepresentable(busStop: busStop)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .toolbar {
                //These ToolbarItems don't show up on iOS18, but does show up in iOS17
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    BusStopTitleView(busStop: busStop)
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button {
                        busStopsViewModel.updateBusStopFavourite(busStop: busStop)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "star")
                    }
                }
            }
            
    }
}

struct BusStopDetailViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    //...
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> BusStopDetailController {
        let controller = BusStopDetailController()
        controller.busStop = busStop
        return controller
    }
}

Results:
On iOS17, which is the expected results:

But on iOS18, this is what I see, where toolbaritems are all not displayed:


Your UIViewControllerRepresentable needs some let properties and you need the update func to use them to update the view controller

@malhal I don't understand, which UIViewControllerRepresentable are you talking about?

@Koh I have removed some properties from your code and tried to reproduce the issue with this code https://gist.github.com/immanaro2497/de49fd5a72037703439774c4dd4bf937 but I can see toolbar items in iOS 18. is the issue reproducible with this code?

@koh erm the one you coded

@Koh Hey, have you found a solution?

@NikitaErmolenko i have not found a solution

@Koh I found out that the problem is related to TabView. In my case a broken UIHostingController was embedded in tabbar. So maybe you have the similar case. I'm still trying to find a workaround...
